# python aiobotocore recursive deletion

Tags: python, amazon-s3, botocore

I am using `aiobotocore` version 2.5.0 in python. (can't use any alternatives)

My bucket name is shop and it has multiple directories (keys)

```
s3://shop/food/vegetables
```

I want to recursively delete all files that are in **vegetables** directory or delete the entire directory (both options work)

How can I do this? Could not find any examples for recursive deletion in documentation - https://aiobotocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Currently, I can delete only specific file with full path of it.

Comment: You'll need to call `list_objects` one more more times to get a list of objects to delete and delete them in turn.